What does "Multi-bit ECC" reported by dmidecode mean?
On some servers, dmidecode --type 16 reports:
...
Physical Memory Array
    Location: Other
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
...

What does the "Multi-bit ECC" mean?
I'm asking because I've only seen single-bit ECC RAMs, and dmidecode reports Single-bit ECC on many computers installed with such RAMs.
Is "Multi-bit ECC" RAM real physical hardware or some software/hardware configuration that makes them function like multi-bit ECC?

"Single-bit ECC" means that if a single bit of the word is in error when read from the RAM, then it will be detected and corrected. If more than one bit is in error, then no correction is possible, but the error is reported. "Multi-bit ECC" means that if N bits of the word are in error when read from the RAM, then they will be detected and corrected. If more than N bit are in error, then no correction is possible, but the error is reported. For speed considerations, the ECC in RAM modules requires hardware.

What does dmidecode -t 17 report for Total Width and Data Width? On a system with Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC I get Total Width: 72 bits and Data Width: 64 bits. Expect with Multi-bit ECC the ratio between Total WidthandData Width` is greater.
